# How to detect circular references in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, solr, circular-reference

I am developing a daemon script in NodeJS which makes it possible to query (in our case) SolR multiple times at the same time. To be more in detail, we have a big application written in PHP and on some pages more SolR requests are required. NodeJS was the solution for us because with NodeJS I was able to do multiple HTTP requests to our SolR server. It already is proven that it saves a lot of time.

The point is, everything works okay and like expected but the daemon will run forever. This means, if there is a memory leak, even when it's really small it's a (big) problem. I am debugging some days now and reduced a lot of the memory usage by just try and error. But I can't get managed that there is no leaking at all.

I have been searching over the web and I think circular references is my problem. My question is how to avoid them? Sometimes it looks impossible to me. I tried to search something for profiling my memory usage in NodeJS but the https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler is broken unfortunetly.

I am from a PHP background so event-driven developing etc is a little new for me. I was wondering if anyone could determine possible leaking in the following code and explain me why:

```
  function ProxyHttpServer () {
  this.httpServer = http.createServer();
  this.configuration = new ProxyConfiguration();

  var logWriter = new ProxyLogWriter();

  /**
   * This is the error event which occurs when the deamon is started
   * and encounters that already 'something' is listening to the same port, and tries restarting
   * for several times.
   */
  ProxyHttpServer.prototype.serverError = function(e) {
      this.configuration = new ProxyConfiguration();

      if (e.code == 'EADDRINUSE') {                
          if(this.configuration.numRestart > 0) {
              console.log('Address and/or port already in use, retrying (' 
                  + this.configuration.numRestart + ' attempts left)', 'WARNING');

              this.configuration.numRestart -= 1;

              setTimeout(function () {                    
                  self.httpServer.listen(this.configuration.port, this.configuration.host);
              }, 1000);                    
          } else {
              console.log('I tried my best, but i\'m too tired now, check ps -fauxwww | grep http-query-daemon to ' 
                  + 'see if this process is running already.', 'ERROR');
          }
      }

      return ;
  }

  ProxyHttpServer.prototype.requestListener = function(request, response) {
      this.proxyHttpClient = new ProxyHttpClient();
      this.proxyHttpResponseWriter = new ProxyHttpResponseWriter();

      this.proxyHttpClient.request = request;                        
      this.proxyHttpClient.response = response;                        
      this.proxyHttpClient.proxyHttpResponseWriter = this.proxyHttpResponseWriter;
      this.proxyHttpResponseWriter.response = response;

      this.proxyHttpClient.validate();

      switch(this.proxyHttpClient.getRoute()) {
          case 'stat' :
              logWriter.writeLog(this.proxyHttpClient);
              break;                
          case 'request' :
              this.queries = this.proxyHttpClient.getQueries();         
              this.logger = new ProxyLogger();                    

              for(var i in this.queries) {                                                           
                  this.httpRequest = new ProxyQueryRequest(this.queries[i], {
                      'client' : this.proxyHttpClient, 
                      'responseWriter' : this.proxyHttpResponseWriter, 
                      'queries' : this.queries,
                      'logger' : this.logger,
                      'finish' : function(responseXml, startTime, endTime, url, objectArguments) {
                          console.log('Request finished in ' + (endTime - startTime) + ' microsends', 'INFO');

                          objectArguments.responseWriter.addDocument(responseXml);

                          console.log(objectArguments.responseWriter.getNumDocs() + ' docs written, ' 
                              + objectArguments.queries.length + ' queries', 'INFO');

                          objectArguments.logger.addRequest((endTime - startTime), url, startTime);

                          //fire writer if all requests are finished
                          if(objectArguments.responseWriter.getNumDocs() == objectArguments.queries.length) {
                              objectArguments.responseWriter.writeResponse();                                             
                          }

                          responseXml = null;
                          startTime = null;
                          endTime = null;
                          url = null;
                          objectArguments = null;

                          return ;                            
                      },
                      'error' : function(message, objectArguments) {
                          objectArguments.responseWriter.writeError(message, true);
                      }
                  })        
                  .execute();
              }            
              break;
          default :
              this.proxyHttpResponseWriter.writeError('There is no valid route');
              break;                    
      }

      this.proxyHttpClient = null;
      this.proxyHttpResponseWriter = null;
      this.queries = null;
      this.logger = null;
      this.httpRequest = null;

      return ;
  };
```

I can't post the full code cause it's more then 500 rows, if anyone would like it I could post it in pastebin.
Or could anyone refer me to good documentation about this topic?